# Why isn't my class selector for this nested anchor tag working?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I am trying to get an element to display when hovering another element. I already have other elements that works perfectly as-is, but one of them I just cannot seem to hit. I've tried using both `>` and `~`, and just `:hover`. Regardless what I try, I cannot seem to target it.

The page is made with Elementor in WP, but don't mind it, all I need is knowledge of how to hit target the right element.

My code is as follows:

```css
.elementor-post__thumbnail {
  position: relative;
}

.elementor-post__thumbnail img {
  position: relative;
}

.elementor-post__thumbnail:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
  background: #0E122E;
}

.elementor-post__thumbnail:hover:after {
  opacity: .9;
}

.elementor-post__thumbnail::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
  background: #0E122E;
}

.elementor-post {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


/* Image Post Title (The one I cant target when hovered) */

.elementor-post__text .elementor-post__title a {
  opacity: 0;
  text-align: right!important;
  color: white!important;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5%;
  right: 0;
  font-family: "rbn02-medium", Sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100!important;
  font-size: 32px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}


/* + Icon Hover */

.elementor-post__thumbnail:before {
  content: "+";
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  color: #0E122E;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.7em;
  font-weight: 900;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 999;
}

.elementor-post__thumbnail:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<article class="elementor-post elementor-grid-item post-240171 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-middagsretter category-opskrifter">

  <a class="elementor-post__thumbnail__link" href="http://pagelink.com/">
    <div class="elementor-post__thumbnail">
      ::before
      <img width="1080" height="1350" src="imgpath.jpeg" class="attachment-full size-full" alt="alt tag" loading="lazy"> :::after
    </div>
  </a>

  <div class="elementor-post__text">
    <h3 class="elementor-post__title">
      <a href="link.com">Link Text</a>
    </h3>
  </div>

</article>
```

The element I can't target is the image post title - the `<a>` within `.elementor-post__text .elementor-post__title`.

I am trying to do `opacity: 1;` whenever the main container is hovered upon. Anyone who can tell me if I am using a wrong selector, if it is even doable, or what else I might be doing wrong? All the other hover-elements shows just fine!

Comment: Which element do you mean by "main container" when you write "whenever the main container is hovered"?

Comment: Sorry that wasn't clear! The others are targeted through .elementor-post__thumbnail so I'm thinking that one. Since .elementor-post__text .elementor-post__title a is not a direct decendant of .elementor-post__thumbnail I'm also wondering if it's even possible!

Comment: Seems like the answer was starting me at the face - targeting the first article / main container did it! I do feel silly for not realizing that earlier

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sibling selector following the `:hover`, like `.elementor-post__thumbnail__link:hover + .elementor-post__text > .elementor-post__title > a { ... }`:

```css
.elementor-post__thumbnail {
  position: relative;
}

.elementor-post__thumbnail img {
  position: relative;
}

.elementor-post__thumbnail:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
  background: #0E122E;
}

.elementor-post__thumbnail:hover:after {
  opacity: .9;
}

.elementor-post__thumbnail::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
  background: #0E122E;
}

.elementor-post {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


/* Image Post Title (The one I cant target when hovered) */

.elementor-post__text .elementor-post__title a {
  opacity: 0;
  text-align: right!important;
  color: white!important;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5%;
  right: 0;
  font-family: "rbn02-medium", Sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100!important;
  font-size: 32px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}


/* + Icon Hover */

.elementor-post__thumbnail:before {
  content: "+";
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  color: #0E122E;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.7em;
  font-weight: 900;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 999;
}

.elementor-post__thumbnail:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
}
.elementor-post__thumbnail__link:hover + .elementor-post__text > .elementor-post__title > a {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<article class="elementor-post elementor-grid-item post-240171 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-middagsretter category-opskrifter">

  <a class="elementor-post__thumbnail__link" href="http://pagelink.com/">
    <div class="elementor-post__thumbnail">
      ::before
      <img width="1080" height="1350" src="https://picsum.photos/1080/1350" class="attachment-full size-full" alt="alt tag" loading="lazy"> :::after
    </div>
  </a>

  <div class="elementor-post__text">
    <h3 class="elementor-post__title">
      <a href="link.com">Link Text</a>
    </h3>
  </div>

</article>
```